# Cannot cast from derived class to base class

Tags: c++

I cant solve it. I have two classes:

**Spatial.h:**

```
namespace graphics {

class Scene;
class Node;
/**
 * Spatial is the basic object that builds the scene. Every class that happens to be in the scene is a spatial
 * 
 */
class Spatial {

public:

    /** A spatial must be renderable */
    virtual void render() = 0;

    /** Get the scene that the spatial belongs to*/
    Scene* getScene();

    /** Set the parent of this spatial to node or to null */
    virtual void setParent(Node* parent) ;


protected:
    /** The scene that the spatial belongs to */
    Scene* scene;

    /** The parent element of the spatial */
    Spatial* parent;


private:


};
```

}

**Spatial.cpp:**

```
namespace graphics {

    Scene* Spatial::getScene() {
        return this->scene;
    }

    void Spatial::setParent(Node* parent) {
        this->parent = parent; // ERROR: cannot convert 'graphics::Node*' to 'graphics::Spatial*' in assignment

        printf("set parent from spatial");
    }
}
```

**Node.cpp:**

```
namespace graphics {

    /**
     * Render the children elements of the node
     */
    void Node::render() {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < children.size(); i++) {
            Spatial* child = children.at(i);
            child->render();
        }
    }

    void Node::addChild(Spatial* spatial) {
        children.push_back(spatial);
        spatial->setParent(this);
    }

    void Node::setParent(Spatial* parent) {
        printf("setparent from node"); 
    }

}
```

**Node.h**

```
namespace graphics {

    using namespace std;

    /** 
     * Node contains different spatial elements which can be rendered from inside of it 
     * If node contains other nodes, then the rendering process is said to recursive:
     * - first element to be drawn in this case is the deepest drawable spatial
     */
    class Node : public Spatial {
    public:
        Node();
        Node(const Node& orig);

        /** Render all childrens of the node within a given scene */
        virtual void render();

        /** Add a child to this node*/
        void addChild(Spatial* spatial);

        /** temporrar y*/
        virtual void setParent(Spatial* parent);

        virtual ~Node();

    protected:

        /** All the children elements of the Node */
        vector<Spatial*> children;


    private:

    };
}
```

At compile time I got the error:

> cannot convert 'graphics::Node*' to 'graphics::Spatial*' in
>   assignment ....

Why? I'm assigning a derived class pointer to base class pointer. Elsewhere it works. What's wrong with that?

Comment: It should be n1->addChild instead of n1.addChild but it must be a typo

Comment: Your Node.cpp and Node.h are the wrong way round.

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, I've corrected it.

Comment: @Banex Corrected also

Comment: At which line do you get this error?

Comment: I think the problem is with the forward definition of `Node` (that depends on `Spatial`) before `Spatial` and the splitting in 2 header files. Combine the 2 headers and 2 cpp into one header and one cpp, and take care of the order of definition and implementation.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi

It's in the Spatial.cpp - I've marked it with with comment.

Comment: Since Spatial is derived from Node, would it make more sense to make 'void addChild(Node* spatial);' and 'virtual void setParent(Node* parent);' in Node class?

Comment: @Andro47 No. Node is derived from Spatial.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. There is a lot of code and a small screen and I got confused.

Comment: Answers to your last question pretty much cover what's wrong in this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954396/base-and-derived-class-in-one-header

Comment: What compiler are you using? I don't encounter the error in VS2013.

Comment: @Lilshieste
Mingw g++.

Comment: @Lilshieste Right... it compiles correctly in VS. It compiled in VS2010. 
That's really weird what's going on here.

Comment: Not enough info to diagnose. VTC.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't included Node.h in Spatial.cpp, so the compiler doesn't know they're related.

You managed to get basic recognition of Node by an incomplete type declaration, but that's not enough. You need to include Node.h in Spatial.cpp to complete the picture.

Comment: Then please edit your code to reflect _accurately_ your problem. As shown here _none_ of these cpp files will compile. They need includes which you have not shown.

Comment: The files will compile, they compile well if the assignement is removed.

Comment: They can't. In Spatial.cpp, Scene, Spatial and Node are all undefined. I repeat: the code as shown here cannot compile in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, not *"why"*, but *"Where's the `Node` declaration in `Node.h`?"*. When the compiler parses `Node.h`, it already should be told that it's a child class of `Spatial`. I think you just mixed-up the definition file (`*.cpp`) and declaration file (`*.h`).

Also - if you want to call member functions of classes by pointers, you should use `operator->`, not `operator .`.

Comment: Not really an answer, is it?

Comment: I think he mislabelled `Node.h` and `Node.cpp`

Comment: @acraig5075 A rhetorical question is by itself an answer. Wiki says: _"A rhetorical question is a figure of speech in the form of a question that is asked in order to make a point."_

Comment: @lukasz1985 if knowing what's wrong is worth `-1`, I'll take it any day :)

Comment: @PawełStawarz Sure, that's why you get -1. That's the purpose of this site :)

Comment: @lukasz1985 judging by the score of your question it surely is. It's funny how you're impolite to people making effort to point you out to the propper place.

Comment: @PawełStawarz I wish inteligent people to make effort to point to the proper place. I don't think that people who make rhetorical questions that miss the whole point are inteligent, because I've already stated the error statement that has nothing to do with your "fixes".

Comment: @lukasz1985 I've made my points before you got comments and fixed anything. I'm not gonna explain myself tho, because I don't need to. After people read your comments, I doubt anyone will try to help you, so you're hurting yourself, not me. `-2` points doesn't matter much, since I got `+10` anyway, because my answer __does__ make a point. A point you don't like with your ego, but a point nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

After I realized that previous (deleted) answer was wrong and after some tweaking to you code, I was able to make it compile with vs2010.  But maybe the following might help:

this->parent = dynamic_cast(parent)

Comment: The opposite of what you say is true.

Comment: @lukasz1985 sorry to add confusion to the confusion then!

Comment: The problem is that it compiled in vs2010 as it is. Still for some reason it's fighting back in MinGW g++. 
Your idea is almost correct with the exception that I don't want to use static cast, where everything should work as expected without any errors that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code (in short)

```
class B;

class A
{
    A* pointerToB;
public:
    void setPointer(B* b)
    {
        pointerToB = b;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
};
```

... doesn't work because at the time the compiler(*) "works" on `pointerToB = b` it doesn't know really, what `B` is - by the forward declaration it only knows that a class `B` exist.

What works (among other possibilities maybe) is:

```
class B;

template<typename T>
class A
{
    A* pointerToB;
public:
    void setPointer(T* b)
    {
        pointerToB = b;
    }
};

class B : public A<B>
{
};
```

Now the compiler creates `A<B>` when it is - first - needed which is at the declaration of `B`. But *then* it knows that `B` derives from *that* `A`.

There is even a name for that: [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) or CRTP.

(*) Using VS2012.

Comment: In VS2012 this the all the stuff compiles so... not a solution. I'll correct my question that I mean g++ or any compiler, actually.

Comment: BTW the first code snippet does **not** compile in VS2012. OK, then try this code with g++, I'm curious whether it compiles. Even better: Apply this to your project.